# CSS Image Clipping as Full Screen

Tags: html, css

I am by no means a CSS expert (as you can see from my code) but I almost got this working the way I want but I was having some slight formatting problems.  Basically I am trying to make a page that will go through a ppt deck (exported as .jpgs).  It is extremely straight forward with only 2 buttons that go to the next or previous slide and displays the image full screen.

The issue I am seeing is the image keeps getting cropped, specifically the top.  It will often display fine but when I switch images the top 5ish% of the screen is getting clipped no matter how much I play with the padding.  Hopefully this is an easy fix... any help would be greatly appreciated...

```html
<html>
<head>

    <style>

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .bg {
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("Slide1.JPG");
            /* Full height */
            height: 90%;
            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .center {
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
            top: 100%;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: #0033ff; /* Blue */
            border: solid;
            border-width: medium;
            border-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 2px 2px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            height: 5%;
            width: 40%;
            font-size: 100%;
        } 

    </style>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(autoNextSlide, 8000);
        var clicks = 1;
        var isPaused = false;
        var time = 0;

        function pictureBack() {
            clicks -= 1;

            checkImage("Slide" + clicks + ".JPG", function () { }, function () { clicks = 1; });
            // alert("slides/Slide" + clicks + ".JPG");
            var str_image = 'background-image: url("Slide' + clicks + '.JPG");';
            document.getElementById('bkground').style.cssText = str_image
            isPaused = true;
            time = 0;
        }

        function pictureNext() {

            clicks += 1;

            checkImage("Slide" + clicks + ".JPG", function () { }, function () { clicks = 1; });
            //alert("slides/Slide" + clicks + ".JPG");
                var str_image = 'background-image: url("Slide' + clicks + '.JPG");';
                document.getElementById('bkground').style.cssText = str_image
                isPaused = true;
                time = 0;
        }
        function checkImage(imageSrc, good, bad) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = good;
            img.onerror = bad;
            img.src = imageSrc;
        }
        function autoNextSlide() {
            if (isPaused) {
                time++;
                if (time > 4) {
                    isPaused = false
                };
                //isPaused = true
                //alert("is paused")
            } else {
                pictureNext();
                time = 0;
                isPaused = false;
            };

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="bg" id="bkground">
        <div class="center">
            <p><input type="button" class="button" id="theButton" value="Previous" onclick="pictureBack()" style='float:left;' padding="10%"></p>

            <p><input type="button" class="button" id="theButton2" value="Next" onclick="pictureNext()" style='float:right;'></p>
        </div>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might help to include some sample images with https://placeholder.com/ or similar so we can see the issue

Comment: why are you expecting height:90% to cover 100%?

Comment: by "full screen", you mean "(except the space taken by the buttons)", or trully full screen and the buttons stacked over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

> ```
>   .bg {
>        /* The image used */
>        background-image: url("Slide1.JPG");
>        /* Full height */
>        height: 90%;
>        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
>        background-position: center;
>        background-repeat: no-repeat;
>        background-size: 100% 100%;
>    }
> ```

Instead of:

> ```
>   .bg {
>        /* The image used */
>        background-image: url("Slide1.JPG");
>        /* Full height */
>        height: 90%;
>        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
>        background-position: center;
>        background-repeat: no-repeat;
>        background-size: cover;
>    }
> ```

Cover makes the image cover the element in it's entirity but cuts off the image.
With `100% 100%` it's makes it fit fully no matter what. It may skew the image a tad on some devices but it you aren't worried about mobile use, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, background-size: 100% 100%; did the trick!